# Show layouts pages based on membership roles

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, layouts

Hi In a claims  based SP site and we have multiple membership roles. I have lot of application pages in the layouts folder is there an effective way (apart from handling them in code behind) to authorize application pages in the layouts page based on roles (only certain membership role can view a particular page others will redirected to custom no access page). Any helpful suggestions and links would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find another answer besides the codebehind (I doubt you will) simply create a base class for your pages that applies the rule:

```
public class MembershipRoleLayoutsPageBase : LayoutsPageBase
{
     public override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
     {
          //check permissions, redirect otherwise
     }
}
```

On MyAppPage1.aspx

```
public class MyAppPage1 : MembershipRoleLayoutsPageBase  
{
  // page stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can play with Web.Config and try applying [ASP.NET Membership: Role Based Security](http://programming4.us/security/1264.aspx)..

As it was previously asked on Stack Overflow:
[Securing Application Pages in SharePoint 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369366/securing-application-pages-in-sharepoint-2010)